# Raise your Stick or your  Hand

Tags: beshalach

וְאַתָּה הָרֵם אֶת מַטְּךָ וּנְטֵה אֶת יָדְךָ

The Posuk first says pick up the stick and then says stick out your hand shouldn't it be stick out you stick being that it is my Hand why the change what happened to the Stick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Kli Yakar translates הָרֵם אֶת מַטְּךָ as **drop** your stick. Since the Mitzriyim said that without the stick Moshe was powerless. Hashem told Moshe to drop the stick and use his hands.